# Search in Varbinary column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to search a keyword's count/repetition in a varbinary column but I am not able to. Can someone help me?

I tried putting the data into a text file & reading from it but I am unable to keep the position of the keyword as soon as it fetches, so the count logic failed there.

I tried this first but rank is giving me undesired values:-

```
SELECT *
FROM
     [AATS_NY].[dbo].[AATS_Fulltext_CandidateProfile_Details] AS FT_TBL
            INNER JOIN
      CONTAINSTABLE([AATS_NY].[dbo].[AATS_Fulltext_CandidateProfile_Details],
                    [Document], 'JAVA') AS KEY_TBL
            ON
                FT_TBL.[DocID] = KEY_TBL.[KEY]
 ORDER BY KEY_TBL.RANK DESC
```

The problem is rank is not returning the exact count of keyword contained in the file.

Comment: Show what you've tried, sample data and desired outcome.

Comment: If you have more to add to your question (and especially if that "more to add" is code), it's better to *edit* your question to add that information. If you're adding code, highlight the block and hit the `{}` button and we get nice syntax highlighting too.

Comment: @peterm, did you find anything suitable for my problem... tks in advance

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, can u plz help me out of my problem. Tks in advance...

Comment: I tried to help by editing your question so that it's easier for other people to help you (and you can now delete several of your comments now that the text is in the question) but I'm not that good with Full Text Search and don't currently have the time available to start investigating just to be able to answer your question. Be patient, and if you've still not got any answers by tomorrow, think about what else you might be able to edit into your question (e.g. sample data, expected results) to make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I am now getting no of occurrences the keyword 'java' is coming in the Resume (which is stored in the Image Column). I have got nearer to the exact count of the keyword in the CV but ultimate problem is that the internal algo for CONTAINSTABLE or freetext is hard coded in the sql. The rank which is returned will always be an approximation, not exact. Do I have to make my own algo to get exact count of the occurences?

Comment: Thanks all, I ultimately solved the problem from a MS Forum...